# Show the map $i_g(x) =gxg^{-1}$ is an isomorphism of itself

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $G$ be a group and let $g$ be one fixed element of $G$, show the map $i_g$ such that $i_g(x) = gxg^{-1}$ for $x \in G$, is an isomorphism of $G$ with itself.

Not sure how to attack this one, I can see that it's just an identity mapping. Just not sure where to start with it. If I am understanding $i_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ correctly it's $g$ acting on $x$ by whatever the operation is then that acting on $g$ inverse restoring $x$? Is that right?

EDIT: if $g=e$ then that makes sense to me because $e$ is its own identity thus $g^{-1}=e$ as well.

Comment: do you mean $i_g(x) = gxg^{-1}$?

Comment: yes, the prime notation is used in my book for inverse

Comment: Well it is not identity necessarily, your reasoning only works with commutativity, but not in general. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\bullet$ $i_g$ is a group homomorphism: $i_g(x_1x_2)=gx_1x_2g^{-1}=gx_1g^{-1}gx_2g^{-1}=i_g(x_1)i_g(x_2)$.

$\bullet$ $i_g$ is injective: suppose $i_g(x_1)=i_g(x_2)$; by def it's $gx_1g^{-1}=gx_2g^{-1}$; multiplying by $g$ to the right and by $g^{-1}$ to the left you'll obtain $x_1=x_2$.

$\bullet$ $i_g$ is surjective: given $h\in G$, let's find $x\in G$ s.t. $i_g(x)=h$; but the last one is by def $gxg^{-1}=h$, from which (as above) you obtain $x=g^{-1}hg$.

Done!

Comment: Equivalently, injectivity and surjectivity are both automatic if you note that $i_g$ has an inverse: $i_{g^{-1}}$.